# Can I use regular expressions or call a method inside a LINQ query?

Tags: c#, linq

I have this LINQ query:

```
var webWordForms = 
   .Select(def => new WebWordForm
   {
       definition = def.definition,
       partOfSpeech = definition.partOfSpeech,
       sourceId = 1,
       synonyms = def.synonyms
   })
   .ToList();
```

Here's the WebWordForm class:

```
public class WebWordForm
{
    public string definition { get; set; }
    public string partOfSpeech { get; set; }
    public int sourceId { get; set; }
    public List<string> examples { get; set; }
}
```

What I need to do is to parse the data that's contained in def.definition part of the query and put this into two properties: definition and examples.

Here's an example of the typical data in def.definition. There's an empty line in between each example.

```
 the trait of lacking restraint or control; freedom from inhibition or worry; "she danced with abandon"

 a feeling of extreme emotional intensity; "the wildness of his anger"

 forsake, leave behind; "We abandoned the old car in the empty parking lot"

 stop maintaining or insisting on; of ideas, claims, etc.; "He abandoned the thought of asking for her hand in marriage"; "Both sides have to give up some calims in these negociations"

 give up with the intent of never claiming again; "Abandon your life to God"; "She gave up her children to her ex

 leave behind empty; move out of; "You must vacate your office by tonight"

 leave someone who needs or counts on you; leave in the lurch; "The mother deserted her children"
```

Here is an explanation of the data:

1. The first part of the data up until the `; "` is the definition.
2. The remainder of the data after the first `; "` is one or more of List examples

What I need is:

1. For the definition to be converted so the first character is a capital letter and for it to go into: `public string definition { get; set; }` #1
2. For the examples after this to go into: `public List<string> examples { get; set; }` #2

Example

```
var webWordForms = 
   .Select(def => new WebWordForm
   {
       definition = #1
       examples = #2
       partOfSpeech = definition.partOfSpeech,
       sourceId = 1,
       synonyms = def.synonyms
   })
   .ToList();
```

I know this is not a simple question but I would appreciate any advice and suggestions on how I can do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible, you could do this.

```
var webWordForms = webforms  // this was just added, use actual collection.
   .Select(def => 
    { 
       string[] splits = def.definition.Split(new string[] {@"; """}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
       return new WebWordForm
       {

           definition = splits[0],
           examples =  splits.Skip(1).ToList(),
           partOfSpeech = definition.partOfSpeech,
           sourceId = 1,
           synonyms = def.synonyms
       }
    })
   .ToList();
```

Comment: Is it not necessary to split at the `def.definition.Split("; \"");`?

Comment: Probably you are right, I might have overlooked it. Let me update.

Comment: @KevinWallis thanks for highlighting this, updated now.

Comment: @HariPrasad - Thanks, I didn't even realize this would be possible like that. Do you think there's a way to also make the first character of the definition that you have as splits[0] into uppercase?

Comment: It is possible, you could do `definition = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(splits[0].ToLower())`

Comment: @HariPrasad - I am getting a syntax error on the line that starts with "string splits". The error is "cannot explicitely convert type 'string[]' into 'string'"

Comment: Resolved thanks.  Should be string[] on the left :-)  Perhaps you can confirm for me.